# Is it possible to make country multi select filter without ag-grid enterprise edition?

Tags: ag-grid

I want to create a country multi select filter in Ag-grid without using enterprise edition. i done with enterprise edition but in current application i don't want to use that but need same functionality what enterprise edition has.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can make a [custom filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/) but it's probably going to be a lot of work.